# In python is there a way to patch a list similiar to using patch.dict?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have some tests and I need to patch a list in the module under test. I can directly blap it but I was hoping for something like patch.dict

For example I have code like this

```
with patch.dict(integrations.PARTNER_SERVICES, { some_key : some_config }):
    self.do_foo()
```

And it cleans up properly after itself even if the test goes south. 
In this case I don't need to add an item to a dictionary but a list. 
I want to be able to use patch.list( in the same way I used patch.dict.

I am sure it is possible but what is the proper pythonic way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok I feel kinda dumb but just figured out how to do it.

```
with patch.object(integrations, 'PARTNERS',[partner_type]):
    self._do_stuff()
```

The name of the list is 'PARTNERS'. This seems blindingly obvious now.

Thanks for the patience in my learning process. Hopes this helps someone else.

Comment: Note that this **replaces** `integrations.PARTNERS` with `[partner_type]` for the duration of the context, as explained in the docs. It doesn't extend or append the base attribute. This is quite different than what `patch.dict` provides, and it's not even clear that this makes sense for a `list` which implicitly encodes positional relationships between the list contents.

Comment: It would be a useful exercise to write something like `patch.dict` that allowed for items to be added to a `list` at user-supplied index locations, which were then automatically popped away at the end of the context.

Comment: That is true. For my use case that is all I needed. My test just needed to be able to stick a 'foo' into the list so it was an expected partner.

Comment: No worries... it's a good question and answer. Unless someone provides you with an answer that implements "patch.list" you should definitely accept your own answer. It is useful!